# “Gift with/upon purchase”

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What's the difference in meaning between "with purchase" and "upon purchase"?

e.g.

1. Enjoy a complimentary tote bag with every purchase of cosmetic goods
2. Enjoy a complimentary tote bag upon every purchase of cosmetic goods

Comment: One preposition stresses the accompaniment, the other the synchronism. There's little change in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

They both look practically similar to me at first glance. Also, I saw "with" used more than "upon" in such situations.

However, if we really want to dissect both the words, here goes:

Using "**with**" implies the free item is provided **together** with the purchased item before or immediately after the payment is done. Refer to the [meaning (4)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with) in MW Dictionary.

So, what does that mean in practice? Possibly one of these things, provided required conditions are met (limiting to the example provided):

1. The customer can pick up the tote bag and take it to checkout (to be billed at zero price or very close). In the case of online shopping, this can mean an automatic addition of the tote bag to the shopping basket at zero price.
2. The tote bag is given to the customer at the checkout desk.

Using "**upon**" implies "**consequent to**". Since the primary definition of *upon* is *on*, refer to [meaning 7(b)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) of *on* in MW Dictionary.

So, what does that mean in practice? Possibly one of these things, provided required conditions are met (limiting to the example provided):

1. The customer is given a voucher at checkout desk (to be redeemed separately for a free tote bag) on completion of payment for the actual goods (same applies to online purchases too).
2. The customer is asked to show the proof of payment at a different desk or mail it somewhere to claim their free tote bag.